# SQL to add position depending on multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, window-functions

I have a table that I am adding a position column in.  I will need to add a numbered position to all rows already in the table.  The numbering depends on 4 columns that would match each other between rows. For example

```
   id| name| fax | cart| area | 
    1| jim | 1   | 4   | 1    |   
    2| jim | 1   | 4   | 1    |
    3| jim | 2   | 4   | 1    |
    4| jim | 2   | 4   | 1    |
    5| bob | 1   | 4   | 1    |
    6| bob | 1   | 4   | 1    |
    7| bob | 2   | 5   | 1    |
    8| bob | 2   | 5   | 2    |
    9| bob | 2   | 5   | 2    |
   10| bob | 2   | 5   | 2    |

would result with

   id| name| fax | cart| area | position
    1| jim | 1   | 4   | 1    | 1
    2| jim | 1   | 4   | 1    | 2
    3| jim | 2   | 4   | 1    | 1
    4| jim | 2   | 4   | 1    | 2
    5| bob | 1   | 4   | 1    | 1
    6| bob | 1   | 4   | 1    | 2
    7| bob | 2   | 5   | 1    | 1
    8| bob | 2   | 5   | 2    | 1
    9| bob | 2   | 5   | 2    | 2
   10| bob | 2   | 5   | 2    | 3
```

I need an sql query that will iterate over the table and add the position.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using: mysql, postgresql, oracle...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select
    t.*,
    row_number() over(partition by name, fax, cart, area order by id) position
from mytable t
```

If you wanted an `update` query:

```
update mytable as t
set position = rn
from (  
    select id, row_number() over(partition by name, fax, cart, area order by id) rn
    from mytable
) x 
where x.id = t.id
```

Comment: Awesome.  How would I insert the result into the position column.  This seems to just display it as a result.

Comment: @Los: welcome. Updating the table does not seems like a good idea. What if a row is with position `1` is then deleted, or updated? You need to look back at other rows and update their position. Instead, you can get the information whenever you need in your queries using the above solution (or you can create a view that includes it, if you are going to use it frequently).

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It  is an ordered list that the user can reorder and it  thus needs to be persisted.  That is why I need to insert the position